# How to get data 3 tables?

Tags: mysql

can u please show me how to query 3 tables using *? thanks

Comment: We are going to need to know more information here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a join on the tables in order to get the columns of all of them.

**Warning**: using * to get all columns is bad practice. You should qualify (name) all the columns you need.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.key2 = t2.key2
INNER JOIN table3 t3
  ON t1.key3 = t3.key3
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you probably don't like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2, table3
```

You have to give way more information.

This generates the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of all the three tables.